# Not defined error in react when directly exporting the functional component rather than assigning to a const

Tags: reactjs, components

Good day, masters! I am newbie in React and I just want to clear out things regarding importing custom components.

I have a functional component that was directly exported rather than assigning to a **const**. What I mean by *exported directly* is this..

```
export default PageLoader = () => {

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("TEST");
    }, []);

    return (null);

}
```

and I am getting this error when importing to another component.

[image]

but if I rather do this,

```
const Pageloader = () => {

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("TEST");
    }, []);

    return (null);

}

export default Pageloader;
```

the error has gone away!

Just confused with the difference. Please help me clear out things :) Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: `export default () => {`

Comment: Oh! Got it, I should remove the function name and it works. I should tried things out hehehe. Thank you!!